# How can I hide a specific software update in Mojave?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update

In the App Store, we used to be able to "Hide Update" for any software we didn't want to update right now.  This feature seems to be gone, as I have an old program I downloaded once many years ago (BlackMagic Disk Speed Test) that I no longer use, and I have no desire to update it.  It's not even installed.

How can I get this update request to go away and stop nagging me?

Comment: If it isn’t installed, how does it know about an update? Was it properly uninstalled? Or just deleted ad hoc?

Comment: I actually have no idea.  I downloaded and used it many years ago on a completely different computer and OS version.  It has never been installed on this computer, but it seems to have carried over somehow since it's currently in my Applications folder.  I'll delete it and see if the nag goes away.

Comment: It must be installed if it is in your applications folder. Or you telling us it is not installed is confusing...

Comment: Don't purchases follow the Apple ID and not the Mac?

Comment: @SteveChambers That's what it looks like to me, that this computer inherited something I had installed long ago on a different machine.  I was only given this machine by a business associate at the end of 2018 (2018 MBP) and have definitely never installed the program in question on it, I used it on my 2011 iMac years earlier.